# what should I do to get the new process using a new command prompt window?

Tags: c++, windows, file, process, console

I got two console applications that the first one runs the second one:

**1_first console application:**

```
#include <Tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(){
 PROCESS_INFORMATION obj1;
 memset(&obj1,0,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
 STARTUPINFOW obj2;
 memset(&obj2,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
 obj2.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
 CreateProcessW(_TEXT("c:\\runme.exe"),_TEXT("hello what's up?"),NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&obj2,&obj1);
}
```

**2_second console application named runme.exe:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char * * argv){
 if (argc>0)
  for (int i=0;i<argc;i++)
   cout <<"**->**"<<argv[i]<<"\n";
}
```

Now my problem is that both applications will use the same command prompt window, what should I do to get them using separate ones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` in the process creation flags (sixth parameter) when you call `CreateProcess`.

```
CreateProcessW(L"c:\\runme.exe",L"hello what's up?",NULL,NULL,FALSE,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&obj2,&obj1);
```

When you call `CreateProcessW` you do *not* want to use `_TEXT` on strings. `CreateProcessW` always takes wide strings, so you should always use an `L` prefix on them. `_TEXT` (or `_T`) is *only* for use with `CreateProcess` (no suffix), so it can change from narrow to wide strings based on whether you define UNICODE/_UNICODE.